# I'm getting slightly different hmac signatures out of clojure and python

Tags: python, clojure, cryptography, hmac

The HMAC SHA1 signatures I'm getting from my python implementation and my clojure implementation are slightly different. I'm stumped as to what would cause that.

Python implementation:

```
import hashlib
import hmac

print hmac.new("my-key", "my-data", hashlib.sha1).hexdigest() # 8bcd5631480093f0b00bd072ead42c032eb31059
```

Clojure implementation:

```
(ns my-project.hmac
    (:import (javax.crypto Mac)
         (javax.crypto.spec SecretKeySpec)))

(def algorithm "HmacSHA1")

(defn return-signing-key [key mac]
  "Get an hmac key from the raw key bytes given some 'mac' algorithm.
  Known 'mac' options: HmacSHA1"
    (SecretKeySpec. (.getBytes key) (.getAlgorithm mac)))

(defn sign-to-bytes [key string]
  "Returns the byte signature of a string with a given key, using a SHA1 HMAC."
  (let [mac (Mac/getInstance algorithm)
    secretKey (return-signing-key key mac)]
    (-> (doto mac
      (.init secretKey)
      (.update (.getBytes string)))
    .doFinal)))

; Formatting
(defn bytes-to-hexstring [bytes]
  "Convert bytes to a String."
  (apply str (map #(format "%x" %) bytes)))



; Public functions
(defn sign-to-hexstring [key string]
  "Returns the HMAC SHA1 hex string signature from a key-string pair."
  (bytes-to-hexstring (sign-to-bytes key string)))

(sign-to-hexstring "my-key" "my-data") ; 8bcd563148093f0b0bd072ead42c32eb31059
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part of your Clojure code that translates bytes to hex strings drops leading zeros.

You could use a format string that maintains a leading zero (`"%02x"`), or use a proper hex encoding library, such as [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Comment: @nstoskrnl what was the final code you ended up with? I'm facing the same problem.