# C# SHA256 Hashing Different To Python Result

Tags: c#, python, encryption, cryptography, sha256

I'm writing a little program based off of a Python code that I have found. There is a few lines I need help with. It is about hasing a value using SHA256 encryption.

The python code is as follows:

```
first = hashlib.sha256((valueOne + valueTwo).encode()).hexdigest()
second = hashlib.sha256(str(timestamp) + value).encode()).hexdigest()
```

And when I execute it, my values are as follows:

```
first: 93046e57a3c183186e9e24ebfda7ca04e7eb4d8119060a8a39b48014d4c5172b
second: bde1c946749f6716fde713d46363d90846a841ad56a4cf7eaccbb33aa1eb1b70
```

My C# code is:

```
string first = sha256_hash((secret + auth_token));
string second = sha256_hash((timestamp.ToString() + secret));
```

And when I execute it, my values are:

```
first: 9346e57a3c183186e9e24ebfda7ca4e7eb4d81196a8a39b48014d4c5172b   
second: bde1c946749f6716fde713d46363d9846a841ad56a4cf7eaccbb33aa1eb1b70
```

As you can see, the values are slightly different. The python code returns two values BOTH with the length of 64 characters, where as in C# the values are 60 characters and 63 characters respectively.

My sha256_hash method is from here: [Obtain SHA-256 string of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/sha-256-hash-in-c-sharp)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your C# output has dropped three `0` characters, that looks like a problem with how you printed that data more than how you produced the hash digests. Apart from those three missing `0` digits, the hashes match.

Comment: @oleksii My first string now went to: fd72a372c9c76ab3aa28f52ba722d1e530011efab6116cee9e49e414c16c638 which is 63 characters long, and the second one went to: e5b76f4165491067188fb49de0db8ac2877fa0b9cbc222d998a1ff891b556a60 which is 64 characters long.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My program then goes on to take characters away from both of these strings, and it relies on them being 64 characters long, however it throws an error because some characters are missing.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479980/q-im-getting-slightly-different-hmac-signatures-out-of-clojure-and-python/), though not the same programming language.

Comment: @ntoskrnl That didn't work. It gives a massive value for each one with heaps of % signs and 'x's.

Comment: Of course it works. But it's Java, not C#.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Well it didn't work for C#. Could you suggest any way to implement that into C#?

Comment: Okay so as @MartijnPieters said it seems that it's something wrong with perhaps the encoding of it, as it just drops the 0 character.

Comment: @user2764359: have you tried my edited answer yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters About how I print the data? The thing is my program then uses these variables, so it's not how I print them. Unless I am understanding you incorrectly?

Comment: @user2764359: I already found the problem, see my answer again. My analysis was certainly correct, it was only the exact syntax of the `b.ToString()` call that eluded me. Have you tried the latest edit yet?

Comment: See [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) for many different ways of converting to hex in C#. Pick whichever one you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hex digest method is not producing length-2 hex values for bytes < 16. The byte `\x08` is being added to your hex output as just `'8'` instead of `'08'`, leading to an output that is too short.

Adjust the format to produce 0-padded hex characters:

```
foreach (Byte b in result)
    Sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
```

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on how to format bytes to hexadecimal strings.

Comment: That made my first string go to: 1472x42x1102x872x1632x1932x1312x242x1102x1582x362x2352x2532x1672x2022x42x2312x2352x772x1292x252x62x102x1382x572x1802x1282x202x2122x1972x232x432x and my second string go to: 1892x2252x2012x702x1162x1592x1032x222x2532x2312x192x2122x992x992x2172x82x702x1682x652x1732x862x1642x2072x1262x1722x2032x1792x582x1612x2352x272x1122x

Comment: @user2764359: Sorry, I'm not a C# expert (by a long shot); I guessed at the `ToString()` format before looking it up..